# Building reports and articles using Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've been reading on how to build reports and sort of publication *ready* articles using Jupyter and markdown and am sort of confused at this point. I have followed several posts and guides including:

- [This blog post](https://github.com/schlaicha/jupyter-publication-scripts/blob/master/tutorial/tutorial.md)
- [Making publication ready Python Notebooks](http://blog.juliusschulz.de/blog/ultimate-ipython-notebook)
- [Writing academic papers in plain text with Markdown and Jupyter notebook](https://sylvaindeville.net/2015/07/17/writing-academic-papers-in-plain-text-with-markdown-and-jupyter-notebook/)

Right now, I am using the following plugins to have a more readable format:

- [collapsible headings](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/blob/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/collapsible_headings/readme.md)
- [python-markdown](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/codefolding) (breaks when outputting to pdf)
- [hide code](https://pypi.org/project/hide_code/)
- [cite2c](https://github.com/takluyver/cite2c)

This was all relatively easy to implement, though I am still having issues with python markdown breaking when outputting to pdf. I am wondering:

1. Especially considering most of the blog posts and tutorials I found are about 4 years or older, are there easier approaches or guidelines for outputting markdown in a jupyter notebook to PDF (or word?).
2. Crossreferences seem to not be possible yet. For instance, I can reference any `figure` that I label manually, but numbers are not automatically updated.

Any suggestions are welcomed!